# TensorFlow nullptr check failed on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, nullptr

I am using the python API of TensorFlow to train a variant of an LSTM.
For that purpose I use the `tf.while_loop` function to iterate over the time steps.

When running my script on the cpu, it does not produce any error messages, but on the gpu python crashes due to:

`...tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc:885] Check failed: nullptr != b.buf_ (nullptr vs. 00...)`

The part of my code, that causes this failure (when commenting it out, it works) is in the body of the while loop:

```
...
h_gathered = h_ta.gather(tf.range(time))
h_gathered = tf.transpose(h_gathered, [1, 0, 2])
syn_t = self.syntactic_weights_ta.read(time)[:, :time]
syn_t = tf.expand_dims(syn_t, 1)
syn_state_t = tf.squeeze(tf.tanh(tf.matmul(syn_t, h_gathered)), 1)
...
```

where `time` is zero based and incremented after each step, `h_ta` is a TensorArray

```
h_ta = tf.TensorArray(
        dtype=dtype,
        size=max_seq_len,
        clear_after_read=False,
        element_shape=[batch_size, num_hidden],
        tensor_array_name="fw_output")
```

and `self.syntactic_weights_ta` is also a TensorArray

```
self.syntactic_weights_ta = tf.TensorArray(
        dtype=dtype,
        size=max_seq_len,
        tensor_array_name="fw_syntactic_weights")
self.syntactic_weights_ta = self.syntactic_weights_ta.unstack(syntactic_weights)
```

What I am trying to achieve in the code snippet is basically a weighted sum over the past outputs, stored in `h_ta`.
In the end I train the network with `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`.

I have tested the script again, but this time with `swap_memory` parameter in the while loop set to `False` and it works on GPU as well, though I'd really like to know why it does not work with `swap_memory=True`.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in the way that TensorArray's tensor storage mechanisms interact with the allocation magic that is performed by while_loop when swap_memory=True.

Can you open an issue on TF's github?  Please also include:

- A full stack trace (TF built with -c dbg preferrable)
- A minimal code example to reproduce
- Describe whether the issue requires you to be calling backprop.
- Whether this is reproducible in TF 1.2 / nightlies / master branch.

And respond here with the link to the github issue?

Comment: I already opened one https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10083, but unfortunately could not make it as detailed as you request. I do not know how to build with debug options on Windows 10. Regarding a minimal code example, I'll try to extend the code I posted further, when I get the time.